# Transfer cookie between domains / browsers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rack

In order to "share" the same session between multiple domains, I'd like two sessions to have the same database/memcache key.

For instance, I want foo.com and bar.com to be essentially the same. Clearly this is not possibly if a the user goes to both domains independently (visits foo.com, logs in, then types in bar.com), however if I redirect from one to the other this should be possible, e.g.

bar.com/x redirects to foo.com/y?_cookie_key=abc

Some middleware on foo.com could detect the _cookie_key parameter and then retrieve the session from the cookie store using the key abc instead of whatever it would have done otherwise. The middleware would set the current session based on that key, and also set that as the new cookie store key for in the cookie that domain/browser.

While this seems theoretically possible, it also seems somewhat hairy and perhaps requires hacking rack. I'm hoping someone has done this before and could provide some guidance or deterrence.

Comment: isn't it the problem that the cookie set on foo just wont transfer over to bar? if you store your session in a shared db/redis/etc not cookie, you can redirect with session id. but cookie will still need to store some credentials. I'm interested in an expert answer too

Answer (score 0):

lets say you got one central domain and several parked domains that use same code/db

I think you can check if server_name is the primary domain and if not, have a middleware script,
to which you pass a 301 redirect with get vars set data of the cookie, so user is redirected there
and from there, redirect back to referrel link, adding a get flag to cease redirection loop
(check for this flag to be unset on primary check if)

and if all this post and redirects happen via ajax, user would never see a thing...